# How can I copy/slice a particular part out of an array with advanced indexing in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

I want to copy a part of an array and save it into another with numpy. The problem is, that the number and position of the entries per row change. I have two arrays with the beginning index and ending index of the part of the row I want to get, but slicing won't take the arrays.

I have tried:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

min_idx = np.array(
    [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
)

max_idx = np.array(
    [4, 3, 3, 2, 2]
)

b = np.zeros_like(a)

b[:, min_idx:max_idx] = a[:,min_idx:max_idx]
```

and want to have for b:

```
target_b = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [0, 6, 7, 8, 0],
    [0, 0, 12, 13, 0],
    [0, 16, 17, 0, 0],
    [20, 21, 22, 0, 0]
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use broadcasting and a mask:

```
c = np.arange(a.shape[1])
m1 = min_idx[:, None] <= c
m2 = max_idx[:, None] >= c
m = m1&m2

b[m] = a[m]
```

`b`:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  6,  7,  8,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12, 13,  0],
       [ 0, 16, 17,  0,  0],
       [20, 21, 22,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Also possible for the last step is `b = np.where(m1 & m2, a, 0)`

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs very true, I reused OP's code but this is cleaner ;)